# How does comparing two chars (within a string) work in Python

Tags: python, string-comparison

I am starting to learn Python and looked at following website: https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/string/
I work on #4 which is "Write a Python program to get a string from a given string where all occurrences of its first char have been changed to '$', except the first char itself."

```
str="restart"
char=str[0]
print(char)

strcpy=str
i=1
for i in range(len(strcpy)):
  print(strcpy[i], "\n")
  if strcpy[i] is char:
    strcpy=strcpy.replace(strcpy[i], '$')
print(strcpy)
```

I would expect "resta$t" but the actual result is: $esta$t

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Strings are immutable, so `strcpy.replace` does not alter `strcpy`, it returns a new `str` object. You'll need `strcpy = strcpy.replace...`. Also, I would avoid using builtins such as `str` for variable names

Comment: I don't think this solves your problem, but style tip: `is` should not be used to perform equality checks. If you're not sure whether `is` is an appropriate solution for a problem, 99% of the time it isn't.

Comment: To piggyback off of @Kevin's comment, this will work for some objects such as string or int, but try something like `a, b = [], []; a is b` and you'll get `False`, even though `a==b` is `True`

Comment: Thank you! strcpy=strcpy.replace(strcpy[i], '$') works now. However, I get following output: $esta$t

I do not understand this since the for loop should skip the first character (at position 0)

str="restart"
char=str[0]
print(char)

strcpy=str
i=1
for i in range(1,len(strcpy)):
  print(strcpy[i], "\n")
  if strcpy[i] is char:
    strcpy=strcpy.replace(strcpy[i], '$')
print(strcpy)

Comment: @pythonlearner that's because you did not actually skip the first character. You reassign `i` with `for` loop. But even if you did skip, `str.replace` replaces all occurrences of the character, or first n occurrences if specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues, first, you are not starting iteration where you think you are:

```py
i = 1 # great, i is 1
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
0
1
2
3
4
```

`i` has been overwritten by the value tracking the loop.

Second, the `is` does not mean value equivalence. That is reserved for the `==` operator. Simpler types such as `int` and `str` can make it seem like `is` works in this fashion, but other types do not behave this way:

```py
a, b = 5, 5

a is b
True

a, b = "5", "5"
a is b
True

a==b
True

### This doesn't work
a, b = [], []

a is b
False

a == b
True
```

As @Kevin pointed out in the comments, 99% of the time, `is` is not the operator you want.

As far as your code goes, [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) will replace all instances of the argument supplied with the second arg, unless you give it an optional number of instances to replace. To avoid replacing the first character, grab the first char separately, like `val = somestring[0]`, then replace the rest using a slice, no need for iteration:

```py
somestr = 'restart' # don't use str as a variable name

val = somestr[0] # val is 'r'

# somestr[1:] gives 'estart'
x = somestr[1:].replace(val, '$')

print(val+x)
# resta$t
```

If you still want to iterate, you can do that over the slice as well:

```py
# collect your letters into a list
letters = []
char = somestr[0]

for letter in somestr[1:]: # No need to track an index here
    if letter == char: # don't use is, use == for value comparison 
       letter = '$' # change letter to a different value if it is equal to char
    letters.append(letter)

# Then use join to concatenate back to a string
print(char + ''.join(letters))
# resta$t
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some need of modification on your code.

Modify your code with as given in below.

```
strcpy="restart"

i=1
for i in range(len(strcpy)):
   strcpy=strcpy.replace(strcpy[0], '$')[:]
print(strcpy)
# $esta$t
```

Also, the best practice to write code in Python is to use Function. You can modify your code as given below or You can use this function.

```
def charreplace(s):
   return s.replace(s[0],'$')[:]

charreplace("restart")
#'$esta$t'
```

Hope this helpful.